# How can I change the order of left expressions in an NSPredicateEditor row template?

Tags: xcode5, interface-builder, nspredicateeditor

I have set up a predicate editor to match string expressions in IB. The list for Left Exprs is fairly long and now I discovered I have to add a new entry near the top. However, I can't for the life of me find a way to do that. I can only add a new value at the bottom.

[image]

There's no context menu, no reorder buttons and drag/drop doesn't work either. Can it be that there's no way to reorder the entries in that list? Or is there an unobvious way to make such a change (as so often in XCode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually simple (did I ask for an unobvious way?): reorder the menu entries in the left sidebar under the first Menu entry. This will implicitly move the entry in the expression list as well:

[image]